# How can I print out "AB\nCD" on the console without going to a new line?

Tags: java, printing, character, literals

I want to print these things on the console

```
AB\nCD
AB\tCD
AB\bCD
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You can print literal ```\n``` using ```\\n```. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the backslash:

```
System.out.println("AB\\nCD");
System.out.println("AB\\tCD");
System.out.println("AB\\bCD");
```

Testing:

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("AB\\nCD");
        System.out.println("AB\\tCD");
        System.out.println("AB\\bCD");
     }
}
```

Output:

```
$javac Test.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M Test
AB\nCD
AB\tCD
AB\bCD
```

Edit:
Code available here:
http://tpcg.io/3KKGIP

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: @ThisuraThenuka How are you using it? https://ideone.com/uRajCd seems to confirm it works.

Comment: My bad bro. I am sorry. You are right

Comment: If I had a penny everytime I heard someone say that to me......................